# Only get one row from the query

Tags: php, mysql

Hello i have a posts_comments table in my phpmyadmin,
and i can see that when i loop out the comments and send the notifications to users who commented then am getting the repeated details which is sending duplicate comments instead of one comment per user_id.

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM posts_comments WHERE id=?";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($sql);
$stmt->execute([$_GET['id']);
$rows = $stmt->fetchAll();
foreach($rows as $row){
$commenter_id = $row['user_id'];

//Inserting a notifation to all users who comments
$insert = "INSERT INTO notifications(message,user_id)VALUES(?,?)";
$stmt = $this->connect()->prepare($insert);
$stmt->execute('some has commented on a post you are following', $logged_user);
}
```

Please help me send only one notification per user in posts_comments

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow.
Please take the [tour] to learn how Stack Overflow works and read [ask] on how to improve the quality of your question.
Then [edit] your question to include the source code you have as a [mcve], which can be tested by others.
Please see: [Why is “Can someone help me?” not an actual question?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/284236).
Also see https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/333952/why-should-i-provide-a-minimal-reproducible-example-for-a-very-simple-sql-query for SQL related questions.

Answer (score -1):

Try using distinct keyword. It will eliminate all the duplicate records and fetching only unique records.

SELECT DISTINCT column1, column2,.....columnN
FROM table_name
WHERE [condition]